# JQuery Mobile - how make grouped button both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: jquery-mobile

In JQuery Mobile you can easily group buttons horizontally by:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a>
</div>
```

[image]

and vertically by

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a>
</div>
```

[image]

but how can I make them group both horizontally and vertically?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a jQuery Mobile **[GRID](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/grids/)**.

```
    <div class="ui-grid-b" >
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a></div>
    </div>
```

Then if you want to get rid of the space between the buttons, add CSS to eliminate the margins:

```
.ui-block-a .ui-btn, .ui-block-b .ui-btn, .ui-block-c .ui-btn {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vzpLdztr/1/)**