# jQuery mobile Button controlgroup horizontal AND vertical

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use the jQuery mobile controlgroups both horizontally AND vertically at the same time? I'd like to create button groups of e.g. 3x3 or 4x4 buttons without any space between them. Using three horizontal controlgroups with three buttons each leaves me with space between the "rows".

Thanks!

Comment: This is a pure CSS job. You have to play with `.ui-controlgroup` style.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688406/jquery-mobile-how-make-grouped-button-both-horizontally-and-vertically/25688785#25688785

Comment: Thank you. The grid idea seems good. Guess I will have to do more tweaking there though as the buttons then don't look the same. For example the buttons in the corners don't have rounded corners, but I guess that should be doable somehow.

Comment: @MarioPreis, I added the rounded corners and created an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a jQM grid and force 0 margins on the buttons. Then apply rounded corners just to the buttons at the corners of the grid:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b gridControlGroup" >
    <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a></div>

    <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a></div>

    <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">1</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">2</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">3</a></div>
</div>        


.gridControlGroup .ui-btn {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.gridControlGroup .ui-block-a:nth-child(1) .ui-btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
.gridControlGroup .ui-block-c:nth-child(3) .ui-btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.gridControlGroup .ui-block-a:nth-last-child(3) .ui-btn {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;

}
.gridControlGroup .ui-block-c:nth-last-child(1) .ui-btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vzpLdztr/3/)**

Comment: Thanks! Looking pretty good already. Now the problem is that if I use a button with only an icon, the button doesn't take all the space of the grid cell. It's as big as the icon itself (18x18 / 36x36). I have no idea when it comes to CSS so I'd have to do a lot of trial&error to fix this. I tried something like "width: 100%" in ".gridControlGroup .ui-btn {", which works for that one button, but then the buttons on the right side of the grid get part of their border cut off on the right side.

Here's an image to show what happens when using a custon icon: [link]http://de.tinypic.com/r/25z1ddy/8

Comment: And this is how I use the custom image:

    .ui-icon-dreambox-green:after {
            background-image: url("/static/images/dreambox-green.png");
            background-size: 18px 18px;
    }

    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-dreambox-green">1</a>

Comment: @MarioPreis, instead of ui-icon-notext, use .ui-btn-icon-top and override the top padding back to 0.7em. Finally change the text to a space:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vzpLdztr/4/ (there are other CSS tricks for this too...)

Comment: Great, thank you. Still it's not optimal (the icon is not completely in the middle vertically, and the borders between the buttons are thicker than they are with regular controlgroups, but I think I can live with that or try to fix it some day :)

Comment: @MarioPreis, centering the icon and eliminating the double borders is just a couple more css rules. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vzpLdztr/5/